# Constant Current Regulator position in a series circuit

Tags: led, constant-current

I'm designing a circuit with 3 LEDs, a CCR (NSI50350), and a power supply in series.

My question is:

**Does it matter where I place the CCR?
Can I design my circuit this way: +V--LED1--LED2--CCR--LED3--GND?**

Regards!

Comment: Anything in series can be rearranged in the correct polarity.

Comment: If it's all in series, the same current flows through each device. Just bear in mind that the tab on that device is connected to the cathode, so it, and the pad it's soldered to won't be at ground potential when you're heatsinking it.

Answer (score 0):

No. the datasheet shows this current regulator being employed on either end of the series LED chain: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NSI50350AD-D.PDF

Comment: It shows the CCR "being employed on either end", but not between the LEDs.